# In C++ is casting to find bad pointers undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

By accident I found that with a polymorphic type using dynamic_cast back to the derived class will throw a 'bad cast' error if the pointer is no longer valid. Is this undefined behavior or could this be a way to check for valid pointers without using smart pointers?

I'm not really against using smart pointers as they serve a real need, but I dislike the syntax. I don't have anything against templated types but I find smart pointers to bloat the code and I'm not a fan of macro's to try and avoid that bloat. I wish C++ included something in the language syntax itself vs using the template feature **but with this question I'm more concerned about what is happening below and if this is a valid and defined way to checking for valid pointers as this gives an exception every time from my tests.**

```
#include <string>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived(){}
};

class Storage
{
private:
    map<string, Base*> storage;
public:
    void AddItem(string name, Base* base)
    {
        if (storage.find(name) == storage.end())
        {
            storage[name] = base;
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    T& FindItem(string name)
    {
        if (storage.find(name) != storage.end())
        {
            Base* item = storage[name];

            return dynamic_cast<T&>(*item);
        }

        throw;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Storage store;

    // force 'd' to go out of scope for our test
    {
        Derived d;

        store.AddItem("test", &d);
    }

    // this will throw a bad cast exception
    Derived& test = store.FindItem<Derived>("test");


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

dynamic-cast needs to deference the pointer to find the proper offset it should be at, dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefined behavior,

one thing you might see:

```
class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived2(){}
};

int main()
{
    Storage store;

    {
        Derived d;

        store.AddItem("test", &d);
    }

    {
        Derived2 d2;

        Derived2& test = store.FindItem<Derived2>("test");//might not throw an exception
        //test might refer to d2
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Messing about with a `void*` buffer and `placement new` and `destroy` will let me insert anything in there.

Just go with smart pointers and learn to appreciate them for the blessing that they are.

Comment: I'm confused as to why test might refer to d2 in your example? Is it because it might have taken the memory location of the original d since it was created after d went out of scope and could have used the same memory that d did when it was valid?

Comment: @user441521 yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example. I don't think I'll ever enjoy the smart pointer syntax as it is, but I'll just use them for the problems they solve. This makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 4):

This is, indeed, undefined behaviour.

`dynamic_cast` needs to look up the run-time type for your pointer, which will generally require dereferencing it, and this is already UB.

Even if an implementation somehow avoid dereferencing the pointer - say by storing a lookup table with the type of each live object, indexed by address range - the fact that your object went out of scope means the same address could be reused by some other object. So, even in this (very contrived) scenario, you wouldn't necessarily get the result you want.

The only answer is to manage lifetimes correctly. As ratchet freak says, smart pointers are probably your best bet here.